# Technology stack required for development of WEB video conference application?

Tags: java, node.js, video-streaming, webrtc

We have requirement to develop a full fledged WEB application which should support the following functionality in any browser/tablets/android/ios?

- video conference one to one.
- video conference one to many.
- screen sharing.
- video/screen recording.

I have already gone through WebRTC which has browser compatibility issues on IE and Safari for video chat and it seems the screen sharing works only on chrome to chrome browser.

Can anyone help me on technology stacks to achieve above?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, the best way to do the above is to write plugins for the IE and Safari that do not (yet?) support WebRTC and use WebRTC for the Chrome and Firefox. You might be tempted to also write plugins for Chrome and Firefox but they are phasing out plugins so that is not a good long term solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try http://skylink.io/

They are already providing plugins for IE and Safari alongwith a stack of SDKs to build an application on top of it.